# Firebase alternatives for Android?

Tags: software-development

I am trying to implement a MongoDB-like interface for making a CRUD over Java objects, like this:

```
public interface UsersRepository {

   public void createUser(User user);
   public User readUser(String fullName);
   public List<User> retrieveAllUsers();
   public void updateUser(User user);
   public void deleteUser(String fullName);
}
```

This is not possible in Firebase due to its asynchronous spirit, thus, is there any alternative?

Thanks